# Remove Avast Firewall NDIS Filter Miniport?

Tags: drivers, firewall, windows-update, avast

First of all, I would like to know what is Avast Firewall NDIS Filter Miniport(and what the hell it has to do with my pc even after uninstalling Avast IS).[image] Then, How can I remove it from my pc? Because the device isn't working properly, when I open it's properties, it's status says:***Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)***
I have tried updating it's driver, but windows update says the driver is up to date[image]
Any, even the device can be configured to work properly, I no longer want it in my pc. I just want to remove it

Answer (score 1):

If you have uninstalled Avast, you can simply uninstall that driver, it worked for me.
I do not know what will happen if you uninstall it with Avast installed, it seems to be related to Avast Firewall, so I advice you to keep it if you have Avast installed.